# Django newsletter by subscribed tags

Tags: python, django, tags, newsletter

I have some Django app, in which you can add tagged objects. There's sth like

```
auto_tags = TagAutocompleteField(_(u'Tags'), default='', blank=True)
```

in models.py file.

How can I create a newsletter which will send an e-mail notification when a new object tagged with one of subscribed tags is created?
Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using [django's built-in signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/signals/). You can register a function to be called when an object is saved, and then send emails to subscibers in that function. The code would looks something like this

```
from django.db.signals import post_save
from my_app.models import MyModel

def my_function(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:
        return  # break if it's being edited
    # check tags for subscribers
    # send email to subscribers

post_save.connect(my_function, sender=MyModel)
```